Integrability proof summation factoring check
In Theorem 3, Chapter 13 on Integrals Spivak is proving that every continuous function on [a, b] is integrable on [a, b]
He goes on like this:

Function f is uniformly continuous on [a, b], so there is some $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x$ and $y$ in [a,b],
$$\text{if} |x - y | < \delta, \text{then} |f(x) - f(y)| < \frac{\epsilon}{2(b-a)}$$

He then proceeds to state that we can pick partitions such that the endpoints of each one are less than delta.
And then proceeds to show that
$$M_i - m_i \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2(b-a)} < \frac{\epsilon}{b-a}$$
I have no issues up to now.
My issue is with the following, he then does this:
$$U(f, P) - L(f, P) = \sum_{i=1}^n (M_i - m_i)(t_i - t_{i-1}) < \frac{\epsilon}{b-a}\sum_{i=1}^n t_i - t_{i-1}$$
And this is where I have an issue, because each $M_i - m_i$ is less than or equal to $\frac{\epsilon}{b-a}$, so when factoring out of the summation it should have been $\frac{n * \epsilon}{2(b-a)}$. In which case, it would have been better to pick partitions such that each sub-interval would give us $M_i - m_i \leq \frac{\epsilon}{n(b-a)}$
Why did Spivak pick $\frac{\epsilon}{2(b-a)}$? Clearly I missing something here.

The expression $\frac{\epsilon}{2(b-a)}$ factors out of the sum (e.g., $2x+2x^2+2=2(1+x+x^2)$, it doesn’t factor out as $6$).

oof embarrassing, which is part of learning, thank you!

That's the kind of thing you don't notice until you ask someone else :). In any case, I looked at Spivak's proof, and I'm also at a loss for why he chose $\frac{\epsilon}{2(b-a)}$ rather than just $\frac{\epsilon}{b-a}$. After all, he never actually uses the value with the $2$ in the denominator. It would seem that $\frac{\epsilon}{b-a}$ suffices. (There are other weird parts of that proof, like when he writes: $\frac{\epsilon}{b-a}\cdot b -a = \epsilon$, which makes me wince a little bit.)

I actually have the same question :) I was hesitant to add more context above
